# What is the Progress equivalent to SQL Management Studio?

Tags: progress-db

I have a progress database that I need to connect to.  What is their equivalent to the SQL Server Management Studio?

The server appears to be Progress OpenEdge 10.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends a bit on how deep you really want to go but "OpenEdge Management" is probably the closest.

If you just need to start & stop the db and take care of routine maintenance you don't need OE Management -- all of that stuff is "in the box" either via "Progress Explorer" or scripting (depending on your taste) and a few utility programs.

To just browse the SQL any standard SQL tool will do.  "Squirrel" is a popular option.

OpenEdge does contain a command line tool "SQL Explorer" that you could also use -- it is installed in %DLC%\bin\sqlexp.exe

Comment: What I'm looking for is something that will let me connect to the database, view the table structure, and, possibly, run some sql queries.

Comment: Close enough.  Thanks.  I ended up configuring a sql server to have a linked server connection to the progress db.  This enabled me to query the sys tables for structure and to run my queries.  It worked well enough to complete the project

Comment: This is exactly what you need to do once you are ready to configure it somewhere: http://www.yellowfinbi.com/YFForum-Connecting-to-10-x-Progress-OpenEdge-?thread=97599